Properly mocking a composable function with vitest
In my Vue 3 app, I use the pattern of having a composable that contains methods that will handle fetching some data from various APIs. The reason they're composables rather than simple functions is that there's some route metadata that I need to grab from useRoute/useRouter, plus data from some other composables in the app.
The composable looks like this
const useHelpMateApi = () => {
  // A bunch of setup code preceding the functions...

  async function fetchHelpMate(id: string) {
    return await fetch(// Fetching occurs here);
  }

  return { fetchHelpMate }
}

I then have a Vue component that will call this API onBeforeMount, like this
// In a <script setup> tag

const { params } = useRoute();
const { fetchHelpMate } = useHelpMateApi();
onBeforeMount(async () => fetchHelpMate(params.id).then((response) => (// do stuff with response));

I'm trying to write a vitest test that checks whether the fetchHelpMate method gets called here with the correct argument (the route's ID), but I can't figure out how to write the test.
I've tried a dozen different formats for this test, the latest one at which point I decided to ask this question being the one below
t('should fetch the HelpMate with the correct ID', () => {
  const spyFetchHelpMate = vi.fn(useHelpMateApi().fetchHelpMate);
  component = mount(BotSettings, { global: { plugins: [router, pinia] } });

  expect(spyFetchHelpMate).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
});

I also tried varieties where I first destructure the function as I do in the component itself and try to mock that, but that also doesn't seem to work.

Have you tried something like this:
const fetchHelpMate = vi.fn();
vi.mock(
    '@your-company/help-mate-api-package',
    () => ({useHelpMateApi: () => ({ fetchHelpMate })}))
);
// ...
expect(fetchHelpMate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)

Or you could refactor your useHelpMateApi method to use
inject('useHelpMateApiToken')

and then in the test-setup you simply provide a mock instead of the real value
const wrapper = mount(Component, {
  provide: {
    useHelpMateApiToken: yourMock
  }
})

